# How to delete the last word of a string if it matches a certain word?

Tags: javascript

`"Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Chile"`

The word Chile appears many times, but I only want to remove the last one IF it is "Chile". If the string was

`"Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Canada"`

this would not delete any word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```js
const result = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Chile".replace(/,\sChile$/, '')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Canada";
var wordToCheck = "Chile";

if(text.endsWith(wordToCheck)
{
  text = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf(wordToCheck),wordToCheck.length);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, `wordToCheck.Length` should be `wordToCheck.length`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to remove the comma

Not cool, not fancy, but works in this case.

var str = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Chile";

str = str.replace(", Chile"," ")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let str = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Chile";
let splited = str.split(' ');

if(splited[splited.length - 1] == 'Chile'){
    splited.pop()
}

let result = splited.join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
const chileAddr = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Chile";
const canadaAddr = "Restaurant Chile - Santiago de Chile, 123904, Canada";

function removeIfEnd(searchTerm, str) {
  return (str.lastIndexOf(searchTerm) == (str.length - searchTerm.length))
    ? str.slice(0, -(searchTerm.length + 2)) // +2 to account for comma
    : str;
}

console.log(removeIfEnd('Chile', chileAddr));
console.log(removeIfEnd('Chile', canadaAddr));
```